# string was not recognized as a valid datetime asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, datetime, web-applications

when i got the above error i tried with datetime journeydate=datetime.parse.... but that also throws a error like a field initializer cant reference the non static field, method or property.

```
public class aaa
{
    public string created_date { get; set; }
    DateTime journeyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(created_date, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // error
}
```

This created_date will be retrived directly from db.. Is there any possible way to avoid the string was not recognized error?

Comment: First of all, please provide a complete example.   The code you show cannot even compile correctly because all code must be inside a method.  Next, what is the value of `created_date` when you get the exception?  If the database returns a NULL value for that column, then the parse will fail.

Comment: It also fails whenever the date isn't formatted properly.

Comment: the value of created_date is 2018-01-19T09:10:52.

Comment: And that string doesn't follow the format, what exactly is the question here? You've said in no uncertain terms that the format is `dd/MM/yyyy h:MM tt` and then you pass in a datetime that contains `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`. `ParseExact` will thus throw that exception.

Comment: fine itz my mistake.. now try to solve my issue not the mistake.. still it shows error with the red line @ my variable created_date while coding-- CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'aaa.created_date'.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is not even close to what you throw in there. You could have at least noticed yourself that the position of year doesn't match.

```
public class aaa
{
    public string created_date { get; set; }
    //This code "runs" so to say. You can't put that in a class. 
    //DateTime journeyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(created_date, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    //Can't do this either, because when will it be called? "runable" code needs to be in a method.
    //for(int i = 0; i < created_date.length; i++){

    //We can however only decalre journeyDate
    private DateTime journeyDate;

    //And then use either a method or constructor to set it:

    public void InitializeJourneyDate()
    {
        journeyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(created_date, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public aaa()
    {
        journeyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(created_date, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    //Maybe the best method is to use a property getter. This will return a diffrent datetime automatically when you change your string

    private DateTime JourneyDateProp
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(created_date, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }

    public void Convert()
    {
        List<string> dateTimeStrings = new List<string>(){
            "2018-01-19T09:10:52",
            "2018-01-22T09:10:52",
            "2018-01-28T09:10:52"
        };

        List<DateTime> dateTimes = new List<DateTime>();

        foreach(string s in dateTimeStrings)
        {
            dateTimes.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(created_date, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows error with the red line @ my variable created_date while coding-- CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'aaa.created_date'

Comment: Thats a seperate problem. Bellow code runs and that was what your question was about. `static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dateString = "2018-01-19T09:10:52";
            DateTime testdate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }`. You are trying to run code in a class. If you move the parse code to the constructor it will stop complaining.

Comment: yes i got, thanks.. also if it is a                                                               
    list<string> = "2018-01-19T09:10:52","018-01-22T09:10:52","018-01-20T09:10:52" can i follow the same prodecure of creating a class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If it is a list of strings, your DateTime property won't work unless you specify an index of which string in that list to use.

Comment: ok, for example, i have list<string> = {2018-01-19T09:10:52,                
                                                            2018-01-22T09:10:52,                                  
                                                            2018-01-28T09:10:52} i need to convert this to list<datetime> because whenver i excute with list<datetime> it throws me error.. so mentioning that as a string initially  and converting it to a datetime at next step itself.

Comment: @suga anser updated. Ask new questions from here on.